# How long before data in cache gets aged evicted out for MySQL - queries run slow then fast

Tags: mysql

For MySQL 5.6 
Queries in our Dev VM linux box w/MySQL take over 4+ seconds to run the first time, then fast after sub 100ms. After a period of time query becomes slow again. I increased the RAM 2+ GB and buffer pool (it was really small using default install number)

The behavior remains, query runs slow then fast once cached. How do we monitor or check if the query is still cached or know when approximate time data gets evicted out of cache.

There's not a heavy load (far as I can tell) to expect data to be aged out.

I believe it's disk io, but I am open to suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the Query Cache is "ON" EVERY!!! Query & Result goes into the Cache and stays there. There a 2 situation when they Query goes out of the Cache.
1) If no more Memory for a new Query, the oldest Querys are purged
2) if you change the Table, so Result may be changed

If you switch the cache to "ON DEMAND" so you can say for each Query if it goes to the cache. So it is possible to put only important Querys into the cache

Comment: Thanks for info! Also with the "ON DEMAND" option that's good to know!